Why does the imaginary time Euler-Lagrange equation imply the potential goes to zero at infinite imaginary time?
On reading up about the bounce solution for false vacuum decay in S. Coleman's The Fate of the False Vacuum I it was stated that the equation
$$0 = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial q}{\partial \tau} . \frac{\partial q}{\partial \tau} - V(q)\tag{2.12}$$
necessarily implies that there is no stable equilibrium point. I understand this as if $\partial q/\partial \tau = 0$ then we must have $0 = -V$, so there is no equilibrium as long as there is a finite potential. They then state that the classical equilibrium point can be reached asymptotically as the limit of $q$ as $\tau$ tends to minus infinity. There have so far been no assumptions that the potential tends to 0 at infinite time. Should this have been assumed or is there (more likely) something I'm misunderstanding?


For the shape of the potential $V$ Ref. 1 is apparently referring to Fig. 2, i.e. the potential $V$ is assumed to have classical false vacuum, i.e. a local minimum $V(q_0)=0$ that is metastable, i.e. not a global minimum.
Assuming $V$ is continuous, there must be another point $\sigma$, where $V(\sigma)=0$.


Ref. 1 next considers a bounce/an instanton between $q_0$ and $\sigma$. Concerning its duration in Euclidean time, see e.g. this related Phys.SE post.

For more information, see e.g. this related Phys.SE post.


References:

S. Coleman, Fate of the false vacuum I: Semiclassical theory, Phys. Rev. D15 (1977) 2929, Erratum Phys. Rev. D16 (1977) 1248.


Thank you. I don’t understand why this 0 must occur at negative infinite imaginary time. Where is the infinity pulled from?

$\uparrow$ See point 2.
